# the IF command cant continue to else for turn off motor dc

Tags: arduino, processing, esp8266

I’ve a project for control a robot in arduino via android.
the trouble is when I press a button for pin 6 (Maju), its turn ON.
But when I press it again its always ON, cant turn OFF.

Here's my code:

```
int kananMaju;
int kiriMundur;
int kananMundur;
int kiriMaju;
#define Kanan A4
#define Kiri 13
#define Maju 6
#define Mundur A5
#define STBY 12
#define PWMA 11 //left
#define PWMB 10 //right
#define AIN2 8
#define AIN1 7
#define BIN1 3
#define BIN2 2
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define DEBUG true

SoftwareSerial esp8266(4,5); // make RX Arduino line is pin 2, make TX Arduino line is pin 3.
                             // This means that you need to connect the TX line from the esp to the Arduino's pin 2
                             // and the RX line from the esp to the Arduino's pin 3
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  esp8266.begin(9600); // your esp's baud rate might be different

  pinMode(STBY,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(BIN2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(BIN1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(AIN2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(AIN1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(PWMB,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(PWMA,OUTPUT);  
  digitalWrite(STBY, HIGH); //standby
  digitalWrite(BIN1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(BIN2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(AIN1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(AIN2, HIGH);
  analogWrite(PWMB, 100); //490 Hz
  analogWrite(PWMA, 100); //490 Hz



  pinMode(Maju,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(Maju,LOW);



  sendCommand("AT+RST\r\n",2000,DEBUG); // reset module
  sendCommand("AT+CWMODE=1\r\n",1000,DEBUG); // configure as access point
  sendCommand("AT+CWJAP=\"PanduGanteng\",\"akhirpekan666\"\r\n",3000,DEBUG);
  delay(10000);
  sendCommand("AT+CIFSR\r\n",1000,DEBUG); // get ip address
  sendCommand("AT+CIPMUX=1\r\n",1000,DEBUG); // configure for multiple connections
  sendCommand("AT+CIPSERVER=1,8080\r\n",1000,DEBUG); // turn on server on port 80

  Serial.println("Server Ready");
}

void loop()
{

  if(esp8266.available()) // check if the esp is sending a message 
  {

    if(esp8266.find("+IPD,"))
    {
     delay(1000); // wait for the serial buffer to fill up (read all the serial data)
     // get the connection id so that we can then disconnect
     int connectionId = esp8266.read()-48; // subtract 48 because the read() function returns 
                                           // the ASCII decimal value and 0 (the first decimal number) starts at 48

     esp8266.find("pin="); // advance cursor to "pin="

     int pinNumber = (esp8266.read()-48); // get first number i.e. if the pin 13 then the 1st number is 1
     int secondNumber = (esp8266.read()-48);
     if(secondNumber>=0 && secondNumber<=9)
     {
      pinNumber*=10;
      pinNumber +=secondNumber; // get second number, i.e. if the pin number is 13 then the 2nd number is 3, then add to the first number
     }

     digitalWrite(pinNumber, !digitalRead(pinNumber)); // toggle pin    

     // build string that is send back to device that is requesting pin toggle
     String content;
     content = "Pin ";
     content += pinNumber;
     content += " is ";

     if(digitalRead(Maju))
     { 
        content += "ON";
        kiriMaju;{
        digitalWrite(STBY,HIGH);
        analogWrite(PWMA, 100);
        digitalWrite(AIN1,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(AIN2,LOW);
     }
        kananMaju;{
        digitalWrite(STBY,HIGH);
        analogWrite(PWMB, 100);
        digitalWrite(BIN1, LOW);
        digitalWrite(BIN2, HIGH);
     }
     }
     else 
     {
        content += "OFF";

     }


     sendHTTPResponse(connectionId,content);

     // make close command
     String closeCommand = "AT+CIPCLOSE="; 
     closeCommand+=connectionId; // append connection id
     closeCommand+="\r\n";

     sendCommand(closeCommand,1000,DEBUG); // close connection
    }
  }
}

/*
* Name: sendData
* Description: Function used to send data to ESP8266.
* Params: command - the data/command to send; timeout - the time to wait for a response; debug - print to Serial window?(true = yes, false = no)
* Returns: The response from the esp8266 (if there is a reponse)
*/
String sendData(String command, const int timeout, boolean debug)
{
    String response = "";

    int dataSize = command.length();
    char data[dataSize];
    command.toCharArray(data,dataSize);

    esp8266.write(data,dataSize); // send the read character to the esp8266
    if(debug)
    {
      Serial.println("\r\n====== HTTP Response From Arduino ======");
      Serial.write(data,dataSize);
      Serial.println("\r\n========================================");
    }

    long int time = millis();

    while( (time+timeout) > millis())
    {
      while(esp8266.available())
      {

        // The esp has data so display its output to the serial window 
        char c = esp8266.read(); // read the next character.
        response+=c;
      }  
    }

    if(debug)
    {
      Serial.print(response);
    }

    return response;
}

/*
* Name: sendHTTPResponse
* Description: Function that sends HTTP 200, HTML UTF-8 response
*/
void sendHTTPResponse(int connectionId, String content)
{

     // build HTTP response
     String httpResponse;
     String httpHeader;
     // HTTP Header
     httpHeader = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n"; 
     httpHeader += "Content-Length: ";
     httpHeader += content.length();
     httpHeader += "\r\n";
     httpHeader +="Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
     httpResponse = httpHeader + content + " "; // There is a bug in this code: the last character of "content" is not sent, I cheated by adding this extra space
     sendCIPData(connectionId,httpResponse);
}

/*
* Name: sendCIPDATA
* Description: sends a CIPSEND=<connectionId>,<data> command
*
*/
void sendCIPData(int connectionId, String data)
{
   String cipSend = "AT+CIPSEND=";
   cipSend += connectionId;
   cipSend += ",";
   cipSend +=data.length();
   cipSend +="\r\n";
   sendCommand(cipSend,1000,DEBUG);
   sendData(data,1000,DEBUG);
}

/*
* Name: sendCommand
* Description: Function used to send data to ESP8266.
* Params: command - the data/command to send; timeout - the time to wait for a response; debug - print to Serial window?(true = yes, false = no)
* Returns: The response from the esp8266 (if there is a reponse)
*/
String sendCommand(String command, const int timeout, boolean debug)
{
    String response = "";

    esp8266.print(command); // send the read character to the esp8266

    long int time = millis();

    while( (time+timeout) > millis())
    {
      while(esp8266.available())
      {

        // The esp has data so display its output to the serial window 
        char c = esp8266.read(); // read the next character.
        response+=c;
      }  
    }

    if(debug)
    {
      Serial.print(response);
    }

    return response;
}
```

I want to when I press button for pin 6 is ON, and when I press it again its OFF. But it's always turned ON, where's my fault?

Answer (score 0):

Maju should be an input not an output
And you need to toggle a state

```
pinMode(Maju,INPUT);

static boolean function get_state()
{
   static boolean previous = LOW;
   static boolean state = LOW;
   boolean current = digitalRead(Maju);

   if (current == HIGH && current != previous) {
       state = (state == LOW) ? HIGH : LOW;
   }
   previous = current;
   return state;

}
```

Comment: its still cant turn OFF.
its always ON when i press the button again :|

Comment: You need to store previous state to detect switch press

Comment: i've change the code like that in void setup, but i cant compile it

Comment: I think you need to start by learning basic stuff and  C or C++ basic. the function should be outside of setup. For example http://www.instructables.com/id/Beginner-Arduino/step15/Button-As-Toggle-Switch/